# Disable Button and apply CSS class to it while message is being sent

Tags: angular, typescript

On an angular 7 component with a form I have the following:

```
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit { 

  message: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.message = this.formBuilder.group({ 
      content: ['']
    });

  }

  onSubmit() {

    if (this.message.valid) {

      let request: SendMessageRequest = { 
        content: this.message.value.content
      };

      this.messageService.send(request).subscribe(
        (response: SendMessageResponse) => { 
          this.message.reset();
        },
        (error) => {
          // Do something with errors           
        }
      );

    }
  }
}
```

And the HTML form is as follows:

```
  <form [formGroup]="message" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label for="content">Content</label>
    <textarea id="message" formControlName="content"></textarea>
    <button class="action" type="submit">Send Message</button>
  </form>
```

How to disable the button, while the message is being sent by the service?

And how to apply a specific CSS class to the disabled button?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass and a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class conditionally( using `ngClass`) to button and display a spinner or make it disabled. In addition to setting css class for disabled, the button attribute can be set to `disabled` and it should appear disabled.

ex:

```
<button class="action" type="submit" [ngClass]="{'disabled': sendDisabled}" [disabled]="sendDisabled">Send Message</button>
```

In component:

```
onSubmit() {

        if (this.message.valid) {

            let request: SendMessageRequest = {
                content: this.message.value.content
            };
            this.sendDisabled=  true;
            this.messageService.send(request).subscribe(
                (response: SendMessageResponse) => {
                    this.message.reset();

                  this.sendDisabled = false; // received response enable button
                },
                (error) => {
                    // Do something with errors           
                }
            );

        }
    }
```

Make sure you have `sendDisabled` defined in your component.
In Css, add styles for disabled class:

```
button.disabled{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a condition using ng-class:

```
<button [class.action]="myCondItion" type="submit">Send Message</button>
```

**TS**

```
myCondItion: boolean = false;
disableButton: boolean= false;
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private messageService: MessageService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.message = this.formBuilder.group({ 
    content: ['']
  });
}

onSubmit() {
 if (this.message.valid) {

  let request: SendMessageRequest = { 
    content: this.message.value.content
  };
  this.myCondItion= true; //showClass
  this.messageService.send(request).subscribe(
  this.disableButton = true;
    (response: SendMessageResponse) => { 
      this.message.reset();
    },
    (error) => {
      // Do something with errors           
    }
   );
  }
 }
}
```